# why my mongodb fileSize is much bigger than storageSize in db.stats()?

Tags: mongodb, diskspace

I have a db named log_test1, with only 1 capped collection logs. The max size of capped collection is 512M. After I inserted 200k data, I found the disk usage of the db is 1.6G. With db.stats(), I can see the storageSize is 512M, correct, but my actual fileSize is 1.6G, why did this happen? How can I control the disk size is just my capped collection size plus index size?

```
> use log_test1
switched to db log_test1
> db.stats()
{
    "db" : "log_test1",
    "collections" : 3,
    "objects" : 200018,
    "avgObjSize" : 615.8577328040476,
    "dataSize" : 123182632,
    "storageSize" : 512008192,
    "numExtents" : 3,
    "indexes" : 8,
    "indexSize" : 71907920,
    "fileSize" : 1610612736,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "dataFileVersion" : {
        "major" : 4,
        "minor" : 5
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is probably because MongoDB preallocates data and journal files.

---

**MongoDB 2**

> In the data directory, MongoDB preallocates data files to a particular size, in part to prevent file system fragmentation. MongoDB names the first data file `<databasename>.0`, the next `<databasename>.1`, etc. The first file **mongod** allocates is 64 megabytes, the next 128 megabytes, and so on, up to 2 gigabytes, at which point all subsequent files are 2 gigabytes. The data files include files with allocated space but that hold no data. **mongod** may allocate a 1 gigabyte data file that may be 90% empty. For most larger databases, unused allocated space is small compared to the database.
>
> On Unix-like systems, **mongod** preallocates an additional data file and initializes the disk space to 0. Preallocating data files in the background prevents significant delays when a new database file is next allocated.
>
> You can disable preallocation with the **noprealloc** run time option. However **noprealloc** is **not** intended for use in production environments: only use **noprealloc** for testing and with small data sets where you frequently drop databases.

**MongoDB 3**

> The data files in your data directory, which is the `/data/db`
>   directory in default configurations, might be larger than the data set
>   inserted into the database. Consider the following possible causes:
>
> Preallocated data files
>
> MongoDB preallocates its data files to avoid filesystem fragmentation,
>   and because of this, the size of these files do not necessarily
>   reflect the size of your data.
>
> The `storage.mmapv1.smallFiles` option will reduce the size of these
>   files, which may be useful if you have many small databases on disk.
>
> The oplog
>
> If this **mongod** is a member of a replica set, the data
>   directory includes the `oplog.rs` file, which is a preallocated capped
>   collection in the local database.
>
> The default allocation is approximately 5% of disk space on 64-bit
>   installations.
>
> The journal
>
> The data directory contains the journal files, which store
>   write operations on disk before MongoDB applies them to databases.
>
> Empty records
>
> MongoDB maintains lists of empty records in data files
>   as it deletes documents and collections. MongoDB can reuse this space,
>   but will not, by default, return this space to the operating system.

---

Taken from [MongoDB Storage FAQ](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#why-are-the-files-in-my-data-directory-larger-than-the-data-in-my-database).